# Approximation and Taylor Series

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation, fractions

Given that

$$ t^{+}=t^{-}+\Delta t\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$
$$ c=\frac{L}{2}\Biggl(\frac{1}{t^{+}}+\frac{1}{t^{-}}\Biggl)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(2) $$
how eqns (1) and (2) can be reworked to
$$  c=\frac{L}{t^{-}}\Biggl[\frac{1+\Delta t/t^{-}}{1+2\Delta t/t^{-}}\Biggl] \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(3)             $$

and why (3) can be reduced to

$$  c=\frac{L}{t^{-}}[1-\Delta t/t^{-}] \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(4)             $$

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? I get $$c=\frac{L}{t^{-}}\left(\frac{1+\frac{\Delta t}{2t^{-}}}{1+\frac{\Delta t}{t^{-}}} \right) $$

Comment: And you cannot reduce (3) to (4). You can check that it is wrong if you plug in some numbers.

Comment: (3) and (4) seems to be almost correct. assuming t+ =10.25, t- =9.75, and L=1000, (1) gives c =100.1, (2) gives 97.8, and (3) 97.3.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a misplaced factor of two in your post, it should be

$$
c = \frac{L}{t^-} \left[ \frac{1 + \Delta t / 2t^-}{1 + \Delta t / t^-}\right]
$$

Now assume that $\Delta t / t^- \ll 1$, you can use the [binomial approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_approximation) , keeping up to first order terms you get

\begin{eqnarray}
c &=& \frac{L}{t^-} \left(1 + \frac{\Delta t}{2t^-}\right) \color{blue}{\left(1 + \frac{\Delta t}{t^-}\right)^{-1}} \\
&\approx & \frac{L}{t^-} \left(1 + \frac{\Delta t}{2t^-}\right) \color{blue}{\left(1 - \frac{\Delta t}{t^-}\right)} \\
&=& \frac{L}{t^-}\left[1 - \frac{\Delta t}{t^-} + \frac{\Delta t}{2t^-} - \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\Delta t}{t^-}\right)^2 \right] \\
&\approx& \frac{L}{t^-}\left[1 - \frac{\Delta t}{2t^-} \right]
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: A quick question, how you determined the term in blue ink?

Comment: @MahdiRazaz The binomial approximation in the link, for $x \ll 1$ you have $$(1 + x)^\alpha \approx 1 + \alpha x$$ in your case $\alpha=-1$

Comment: Dt/t<<1, so the denominator equals 1, and c = (L/t-)(1+Dt/2t-) -- first line -- which is then multiplied by the blue term before applying binomial approximation. Am I right? If so, where is the first blue term is coming from?

Comment: @MahdiRazaz "Dt/t<<1, so the denominator equals 1 ..." no, that would be the case if $\Delta t / t^- = 0$, but that's not what you want. What you're looking for is the case where that factor is small but not exactly zero

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally got it :)

Answer (score 1):

Given
\begin{align}
 t^+ &= t^- + \Delta t,  \tag1 \\
 c &= \frac L2 \left(\frac{1}{t^+} + \frac{1}{t^-}\right),  \tag2
\end{align}

we have

\begin{align}
 c &= \frac{L}{2t^-} \left(\frac{t^-}{t^+} + 1\right) \\
 &= \frac{L}{2t^-} \left(\frac{(t^+ - \Delta t) + t^+}{t^+}\right) \\
 &= \frac{L}{2t^-} \left(2 - \frac{\Delta t}{t^+}\right) \\
 &= \frac{L}{t^-} \left(1 - \frac{\Delta t}{2t^+}\right). \\
\end{align}

If $\Delta t$ is small enough compared to $t^-$, then
$\frac{L}{t^-} \left(1 - {\Delta t}/({2t^-})\right)$
might be a reasonable approximation (plus some higher order terms), but
$\frac{L}{t^-} \left(1 - {\Delta t}/{t^-}\right)$
just seems like a mistake.

Plugging in actual numbers, if we let
$t^- = 9.75,$ $t^+ =10.25,$ and $L=1000$, then
$\Delta t = 0.5,$

\begin{align}
\frac L2 \left(\frac{1}{t^+} + \frac{1}{t^-}\right)
&= \frac{1000}{2}\left(\frac1{10.25}+\frac1{9.75}\right) \approx 100.0625,\\
\frac{L}{t^{-}}\left(\frac{1+\Delta t/t^-}{1+2\Delta t/t^-}\right) 
&= \frac{1000}{9.75} \left(\frac{1+0.5/9.75}{1+2(0.5)/9.75}\right)
 \approx 97.7937, \tag A\\
\frac{L}{t^{-}}\left(1-\frac{\Delta t}{t^-}\right) 
&= \frac{1000}{9.75} \left(1+\frac{0.5}{9.75}\right)
 \approx 97.3044, \tag B\\
\frac{L}{t^-} \left(1 - \frac{\Delta t}{2t^-}\right)
&= \frac{1000}{9.75} \left(1+\frac{0.5}{2(9.75)}\right)
 \approx 99.9343 \tag C\\
\frac{L}{t^{-}} &= \frac{1000}{9.75} \approx 102.5641.
\end{align}

Now let's look at the errors:

\begin{align}
 97.7937 - 100.0625 &= -2.2688, \\
 97.3044 - 100.0625 &= -2.7581, \\
 99.9343 - 100.0625 &= -0.1282, \\
102.5641 - 100.0625 &=  2.5016. \\
\end{align}

So we see that the factor of $2$ in the denominator of
$\frac{L}{t^-} \left(1 - {\Delta t}/({2t^-})\right)$
(in Equation $(C)$)
reduces the error by an entire order of magnitude,
whereas the simple approximation $L/t^-$
has about the same error as either of the approximations in
$(A)$ or $(B)$.
This is not surprising, because by subtracting
$\Delta t/t^-$ when they should be subtracting
about half that value, ${\Delta t}/({2t^+}),$
whoever came up with $(A)$ and $(B)$ overcorrected the
$L/t^-$ approximation by about the same amount as its error.